# Export a function to a .csv or .xlsx file in Python

Tags: python

I am using an apripori algorithm in Python and would like to know how can I export the results to excel or csv?

```py
from mlxtend.preprocessing import TransactionEncoder
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import apriori
apriori(df_one_hot,min_support=0.05,use_colnames=True).sort_values(by='support',ascending=False)
```

Comment: Please be more precise: what type of data your `apriori` function is returning?

Comment: Thanks for the tip Daweo, the function returned a table but could not see the data type, so i did not put it in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the results in a `pandas` dataframe and use `to_csv` to write to a CSV file.

```
import pandas as pd
results = apriori(df_one_hot,min_support=0.05,use_colnames=True).sort_values(by='support',ascending=False)
results_df = pd.DataFrame(results)
results_df.to_csv('results.csv', index=False)
```